# Glove won't move with additional bones

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

I created a rig for my character and everything worked fine. While trying to ball my character's fist, I decided I wanted an extra bone in the fingers.

After I created the extra bones, (thumb 3.l)(index4.l)(middle4.l)(ring4.l)(little4.l)I noticed the extra bones do not move with the glove.

I suspect that object data properties may have something to do with this but I'm not entirely sure. I've provided my link below. I would appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

https://pasteall.org/blend/d8abc1448c26455a934a270946aad7e3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in object mode: Select your mesh, shift select your armature, change to pose mode, select all these bones:

[image]

press ctrl-p -> with automatic weights -> now you can move them:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! This answer solved my problem. Thanks ^_^

Comment: you are welcome!! glad i could help

Answer (score 4):

You can use Chris' solution, but if you want to keep the previous rigging and only parent the new bones you can: Select the armature, shift select the glove, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select the bones you want (shift left click to select several bones), and in the header menu > *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]

Comment: Both your answers are brilliant! Thanks.